# Which model evaluation scoring strategies are appropriate for different regression problems?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation, hyperparameter

Scikit-learn provides [4 different scoring objects](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules) for evaluation of regression problems:

- ‘neg_mean_absolute_error’
- ‘neg_mean_squared_error’
- ‘neg_median_absolute_error’
- ‘r2’

E.g. r2 is a particularly poor choice when the cross-validation strategy includes a very small test size (variance becomes extreme as the test size approaches leave-one-out CV).

When would you tend to utilize each of these four scoring methods for regression model evaluation? What about when performing hyperparameter selection?

Answer (score 3):

I too find the default of R2 to be the not the ideal metric for assessing regression results, as I am typically interested in either forecasting or predicting a value, so the error is more useful. I tend to use the mean squared error (somewhat confusingly referred to as 'neg_mean_squared_error' in the scikit scorer here) when validating my models.

And there is actually even a fifth now, explained_variance (see here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

In terms of evaluation vs. hyperparameter selection, IMO if there is a metric you are aiming for, keep it consistent.